# Add a field in a table and check condition with another column

Tags: mysql, alter

I need to add a field – DOC with Date type to the Registration table also ensure DOC greater than DOJ.I tried this

```
ALTER TABLE Registration
ADD DOC date
CHECK (DOC>DOJ);
```

It shows error.Where i went wrong?

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [prior to MySQL version 8.0.16](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html), MySQL permitted only a very limited version of table `CHECK` constraint syntax, which was parsed and ignored. So if your MySQL version < **8.0.16**, then your `ALTER TABLE` statement would not fulfill any purpose; and possibly the reason of syntax error as well.

Now, if your version is indeed correct; then you are defining **Table Constraint** incorrectly. As per [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html):

> A `CHECK` constraint is specified as either a table constraint or column
>   constraint:
>
> - A table constraint does not appear within a column definition and can refer to any table column or columns. Forward references are
>     permitted to columns appearing later in the table definition.
> - A column constraint appears within a column definition and can refer only to that column.

Since your `CHECK` constraint involves more than one column, it is a **Table constraint**. Also, [`ALTER TABLE` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) to add a new CHECK constraint is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    ADD CONSTRAINT [symbol] CHECK (expr) [[NOT] ENFORCED];
```

Try the following instead:

```
ALTER TABLE Registration
ADD DOC date, 
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_doc_greater_doj CHECK (DOC>DOJ);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE REGISTRATION 
ADD DOC DATE
ADD CONSTRAINT DATE_OF_COMPLETION CHECK(DOC>DOJ);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I encountered same problem, I solved it by writing in two seperate queries

```
ALTER TABLE Registration ADD DOC date;
ALTER TABLE Registration ADD CONSTRAINT check_date CHECK (DOC>DOJ);
```